# forecast data in R with very upward trend

Tags: r, time-series, trend

i want to forecast data with very upward trend. First of all here is my data(units of a product )

```
10493
13666
15590
18868
16008
19973
23929
25011
29010
28804
30239
35830
```

the data is at monthly base..so i have one year data..the product is new so it's normally growing.

as you can see the trend is upward. the number of my data is very few. so if i do a normal forecast like holt winters, arma,arima,ets,etc the forecast will not right.
i tried to forecast this data, and as it was expected the forecast was an upward line..

Now is the real question. is anything i can do to find when the data will stop growing.? i was thinking to do a multivariate forecast with one other product.the other product i think that it has to be very mature and have a lot of data..so i can create a correlation between the two of them and have a better forecast.. i try to explain as better i can my problem.

thanks in advance,
vasilis

Comment: You should probably a try a variant of this question on CrossValidated. There are lots of different ways to come up with a forecast, with differing merits.

Answer (score 1):

Plot your data:

```
y <- c(10493,
       13666,
       15590,
       18868,
       16008,
       19973,
       23929,
       25011,
       29010,
       28804,
       30239,
       35830)

plot(y)
```

[image: resulting plot]

The data clearly does not contain any information regarding a change in its trend. I doubt that you have any data that could change this simple fact. Even the comparison with the mature product is unlikely to help, since you probably can't assume that initial growth is related to when that growth stops.